# Setting the title with Angular

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm trying to work with an Angular app I don't know so much about. It uses TypeScript Angular 1.5. I need to be able to change the page's title. This is what I have to work with. I'm not sure how it works without ng-app specified, but it works.

Is there a way to set the title in the head dynamically? Or would I need to change the ng-controller attr to the html element? If so how could it affect the system?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="sv">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>MySajt</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body ng-controller="AppController as vm" ng-class="{ 'v-dolj-overflow': vm.togglaScroll }">

    <my-header></my-header>

    <div class="v--header-offset" ui-view></div>

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-locale_sv.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `window.title = "What I want";` Plain old JavaScript to the rescue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this with `document.title` regardless of where the controller lives
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/title

Answer (score 2):

It is not good idea to work with `document` or `window` directly. There are some better solutions.

### Your own solution

If you want use `plain old JavaScript` you have to use at least [$document](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$document) or [$window](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window) providers to implement it.

Reasons to use them is: AngularJS providers are testable. If you write tests for your application you can mock `$document` or `$window`. So you will be able to cover all methods and lines by unit tests.

### Custom module

One of the solutions is to use some custom module. Just an example: http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngTitle. There module is not much code.